# Issue with Encryption using Luks in Beaglebone

Tags: c, linux, encryption, luks

I am trying to encrypt a partition of memory device in **Beaglebone** using the library **libcryptsetup**, but I can't add key slot to the formatted partition.

```
crypt_keyslot_add_by_volume_key(cd,CRYPT_SLOT_ACTIVE,NULL,0,"demo",4);
```

This function always returns a negative value and fails to add a key slot, but the same function is working good in my Ubuntu PC.

Suggest me a way to overcome this issue.